# only download html page with urllib2

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to crawl the web with urllib2 and beautifulsoup. But my code ran out of memory with some links like this:

http://downloads.graboidvideo.com/download_filter.php?file=GraboidVideoSetup.pkg&platform=Mac

It's a video download link. when I use urllib2.urlopen(), it will will download the video, which is not what I want. Is there any way to only download the html of urls? I basically want to skip it if an url refers to a video file or other files, but I don't know how to do that.

My code is as following:

```
toy_url=http://downloads.graboidvideo.com/download_filter.php?file=GraboidVideoSetup.pkg&platform=Mac
headers = {'USER-Agent':'crawltaosof'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, None,headers)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout=0.51).read()
```

Comment: Better showing us your code then !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider checking the response header before you use the `read()` method. Here is an example.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>>
>>> request = urllib2.Request('http://downloads.graboidvideo.com/download_filter
.php?file=GraboidVideoSetup.pkg&platform=Mac')
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>>>
>>> print response.info().getheader('Content-Type')
application/octet-stream
>>>
>>>
>>> request = urllib2.Request('http://www.yahoo.com')
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>>>
>>> print response.info().getheader('Content-Type')
text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Ultimately, you will want to test against `Content-Type` in the response header and use that to ensure it is of type `text\html` before running the url through your web crawler. Refer to this wikipedia article on [Internet media types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_text) if you want to learn about other `text` types.